# How to change string of ^ type to char* type in vc++ CLR window application?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm working on a vc++ CLR window application.In this application when I browse the local file system for file selection, the input file path is coming in string^ type ...now I want to change this ^ type to char* type. Help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi

```
IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString);
char* c = (char*)p.ToPointer();
...
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) for more.